# Minimizing computations for evaluating two polynomial simultaneously

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, algorithms, computational-mathematics, computational-algebra

I want to evaluate two polynomials $f$ and $g$ simultaneously, on the same input (in a computer program). These polynomial have only coefficients $0, 1, a , b$ and their degree is less than 700.
I want to compute $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ simultaneously as efficiently as possible. I'm looking for an algorithms that say me how to do that.

For example, let $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + x$ and $g(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx$.
We have $f(x) =  x^2(ax + b) + x$ and $g(x) = x(x^2) + x(ax+b)$.
So we first compute $x^2$ and $ax+b$ and then use them to compute $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Here, the optimization is evaluating $x^2$ and $ax+b$ one time for both $f$ and $g$.

Is there a algorithm that can show us how we should compute $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in fewest computations (for a computer)?  In other words, the algorithm should receive $f$ and $g$ as input and then return an algorithm for computing them.

I guess we can use algebra( some ring theory, ideal,...) or graph theory to model this problem.

Comment: Are the two polynomials of same degree ?

Comment: No, we have no more information of them.

Comment: I don't see why the classical approach could not apply : for degree $n$, it requires $n$ additions plus $n$ multiplications for each polynomial.

Comment: A good algorithm helps a computer program runs up to 2 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

Both $f$ and $g$
are of the form
$af_a(x)+bf_b(x)+f_1(x)
$
(and similarly for $g$)
where the
$f_c(x)$
are polynomials
with all coefficients one
(if I have interpreted
you correctly).

If these polynomials
have stretches where
all the coefficients are one,
you can use

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=i}^j x^k
&=x^i\sum_{k=i}^j x^{k-i}\\
&=x^i\sum_{k=0}^{j-i} x^{k}\\
&=x^i\frac{x^{j-i+1}-1}{x-1}\\
&=\frac{x^{j+1}-x^i}{x-1}\\
\end{array}
$

to quickly sum these stretches.
You can also precompute
$x-1$ and divide
the sum of these numerators
by that.

Anything more
depends on the detailed structure
of the polynomials.

Comment: Don't you think that grouping like this could finally make the calculations more expensive than a classical approach ?

Comment: I think your algorithm cannot find optimum way, even for my above example.

Comment: I don't know. If the polynomials had lots of long runs, my suggestion could help. If not, then no.